# convert seperated string to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

ProjectIds variable is currently returning an object with a string values seperated by a comma. like so :

I am creating an object with code like this which returns me:

```
 const projectIds = scheduleFieldData[config.name].toString().split(', ').map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))
            if(config.name === 'project'){
              console.log(projectIds);
            }


//{label: "10,10,10", value: "10,10,10"}
```

I want the output to be

```
{label: ["10"],["10"],["10"], value: ["10"],["10"],["10"]}
```

What I have tried:

```
 const projectIds = scheduleFieldData[config.name].toString().split(', ').map(x => ({label: x, value: x}))
            if(config.name === 'project'){
              console.log(projectIds.split(', '));
            }
```

But With this I am getting:

ProjectIds.split() is not a function. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: what is `scheduleFieldData[config.name]` supposed to have?

Comment: Its meant to store the project Ids

Comment: in an Array? an Object? as a String?

Comment: The data structure you're trying to create doesn't exist. Did you mean something like:

{ label: [ ["10"],["10"],["10"] ], value: [ ["10"],["10"],["10"] ] }

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable like:

```
let a = ['a'], ['b'], etc..
```

You should have something like

```
let a = [['a'], ['b'], etc..]
```

To convert "a, b, c" to [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]

```
const convert = (str) => {
   str = str.replace(/\s/g, "")
   return str.split(",").map(c => [c])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var projectIds = {
  label: "10,10,10",
  value: "10,10,10"
};

var result = {};
result.lablel = projectIds.label.split(',').map(i => {
  return [i];
});
result.value = projectIds.value.split(',').map(i => {
  return [i];
});
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You really should add some context into what is going on with the answer you have provided. Walk the OP through the code. Answers with no comments what so ever are always going to get flagged as low quality posts.

Answer (score 0):

The result you're trying to achieve is invalid, maybe this is what you're looking for:

```js
const projectIds = {label: "10,11,12", value: "13,14,15"}
console.log(projectIds.label.split(',')); // ["10", "11", "12"]
console.log(projectIds.value.split(',')); // ["13", "14", "15"]
```